# How can I fix this error "Undefined offset: " at Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I get this Error for every row in the data. So around 500 times, but every time with an other Undefined offset.
Heres my Code:

```html
$fl_array = preg_grep('/^\d+\s('. $SelectedTime .':)\d+/', explode("\n", $finalLog));
$count = count($fl_array);

for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++)
{
    echo "$fl_array[$x] \n";
}
```

Comment: What if you change `$SelectedTime` with `preg_quote($SelectedTime, '/')`?

Comment: That would happen for empty result arrays (AKA no matches). Look into [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This doesnt work

Comment: @mario Could you mabye make a sample?

Comment: There are samples in the linked manual page.

Comment: @mario With the foreach I get the right outprint, but with no line breaks etc.

Comment: CR doesn't amount to a linebreak in HTML context. (You didn't mention this; just assuming here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as written here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php: `Returns an array indexed using the keys from the input array.` so maybe smth wrong with your keys:

```
if (isset($fl_array[$x])) {
    echo "$fl_array[$x] \n";
}
```